# Trouble with copying sheets from closed workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

So hopefully yall could help.  I've got this VBA i've pieced together, with the goal of

- opening up a group of xls files each morning & copying all tabs from all files into a single master workbook.

  - Insert the file name that the worksheet came from into the 1st column, & fill that down the active region.
  - then, combine multiple sheets that are similar format into a new aggregate sheet (hence the insert filename into col1)
  - then delete all the old original sheets

So I've got this VBA that does the file importing, and I have another sub() that does the reformating.  The problem I'm running into is that if the workbook has multiple worksheets, the all sheets will get copied, but the filename insert portion only happens on the first worksheet, and it repeats the insert on the first work sheet "i" times, where "i" = the # of sheets in the workbook.

How to get this to be correct, where each sheet gets the filename insert? 
For example, if there's 3 sheets, they all get copied, but the 1stof3 gets 3 columns with the filename.

Here's what I've got going on:

defining strings and popup user selections.  Pops up a directory selection box for user.

```
Function FileNameFromPath(strFullPath As String) As String

FileNameFromPath = Right(strFullPath, Len(strFullPath) - InStrRev(strFullPath, "\"))

End Function
```

defining strings and popup user selections

```
Function GetFolder(strpath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strpath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem & "\"

Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Main file open/copy script

```
Sub CombineFiles()
'Define variables
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim i As Integer, rngData As Range
Dim errcheck As Integer
Dim strpath As String, Title As String

'Path for folder to default to
strpath = "c:\directory"

'Open window to select folder
Set afolder = fso.GetFolder(GetFolder(strpath))
strpath = afolder + "\"

'This keeps the screen from updating until the end, makes the macro run faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'This makes the file read-only during changes
With ActiveSheet
If .ProtectContents Then .Unprotect Else .Protect "", True, True, True,     True
End With

'Cycles through every file in the folder with .xls* extension
Filename = Dir(strpath & "*.xls*")
  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=strpath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

  'Loops through each sheet in file
  errcheck = 0
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Range("A1").AutoFilter
        End If

        Columns(1).Insert 'inserts new col @ A for spec#
        Cells(1, 1).Value = "Filename"
        'Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value = Filename 'inserts name @ A2 and fills down length of colB

        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
        Range("A1").AutoFilter
        End If

        Columns.AutoFit

        Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

        On Error Resume Next:

        Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
        Rows("2:2").Select
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

    End If
Next Sheet

Workbooks(Filename).Close False
Filename = Dir()
  Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what does `fill that down the active region` mean?

Comment: inserts new column @ A, Position1, then copy/paste the filename in row2,col1, then fill that name down the length of rows equal to the length of the data table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you do not qualify the worksheet for the range correctly:

```
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If Sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
    Range("A1").AutoFilter
    End If

    Sheet.Columns(1).Insert 'inserts new col @ A for spec#
    Sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Filename"
    'Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Sheet.Range("A2:A" & Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value = Filename 'inserts name @ A2 and fills down length of colB

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
    Range("A1").AutoFilter
    End If

    Sheet.Columns.AutoFit

    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    On Error Resume Next:

    Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    Sheet.Rows("2:2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

End If
Next Sheet
```

I am not entirely sure if `rngData` is on the `Sheet` so check if that has to be qualified. Same goes for `AutoFilter`rows.
For FreezePanes:

```
Sheet.Activate
with ActiveWindow
    if .FreezePanes then .FreezePanes = False
    .SplitRow = 1
    .FreezePanes = True
end with
```

Comment: I don't see where you change the value of `Filename` here. Unless that's changed, it's going to keep printing that name over and over.

Comment: @dwirony The problem is that the filename is being printed 3 times on the first of the tthree sheets. That happens because it is done on `ActiveWorksheet` because the ranges are not qualified with `Sheet.` when its looping.

Comment: @Viktor K Ahhh I see now. I thought they wanted a different name on each page instead of the same. Got it.

Comment: Excellent!  I added "SHEETS." all over it and it pretty much works now.  One new column on each sheet and the filename dropped down...only 2 small problems arise now.

Comment: Excellent!  I added "SHEETS." all over it and it pretty much works now.  One new column on each sheet and the filename dropped down...only one small problem popped up now.

near the end, I have those 3 lines about freezing the top row.  This seems to not be working.  The goal is to freeze the top row of each sheet, but each sheet seems to be frozen a random/different # of rows down...doesn't seem to be any consistency.  Any thoughts?  

Maybe I should pull that section out and run through the sheets formatting, filtering, freezing in a separate sub() after the import sub(). 

thoughts?

Comment: @surfer349 I believe it doesn't work for a simple reason: ` Sheet.Rows("2:2").Select` will not select because it can be only done on an active worksheet. So either add `Sheet.Activate` before that, or improve your code by fully qualifying ranges and drop `Select` and `Activate` altogether. Also take a look how to use `With... End With`. Finally I would be grateful if you would kindly accept my answer.

Comment: Hmmm...so I'm still new to VBA and not really sure here.  So I tried adding 'sheet.activate' but that seems to just stop the freezing and the copied sheets don't freeze at all.

Maybe it would be easier to create a new sub() that will run through all the copied sheets and format them (fix the font, add gridlines, freeze the top row, add filters, etc). 

What do you think?

Comment: @surfer349 Take a look at my edit - it will freeze pane on the current `Sheet` you are processing. But I am not sure which `Worksheet` you actually want to freeze because you copy it from `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`. If it is for a copied sheed in `ThisWorkbook` than you have to select it with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate` instead of `Sheet.Activate`.

Comment: @Victor:  Hmm...that still isn't working.  I think maybe a separate sub after its all imported would be better, where I can apply a filter and freeze the top row.

I have one more question.  In going through the sheet copies, how can add in an option to only copy specific sheets?  Like sheets that start with the word "DATA" as the name.  The files contain a bunch of extra sheets that aren't all needed.

Comment: @surfer349 Try adding the following if statement: `If Sheet.Name is Like "DATA*" then ...`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to split worksheet

the split point has to be visible, so you cannot set it on a worksheet that is not active

```
    ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView 1, 1, 1, 1    ' show top of worksheet
    ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```